# Referencing controllers from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I'm working with a default .NET Core Identity Web Application solution within Visual Studio. I'm trying to separate all the Identity logic into its own project. My only hang up appears to be here:

```
namespace WebApp.Identity.Extensions
{
    public static class UrlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static string EmailConfirmationLink(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, int userId, string code, string scheme)
        {
            return urlHelper.Action(
                action: nameof(AccountController.ConfirmEmail),
                controller: "Account",
                values: new { userId, code },
                protocol: scheme);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error `The name 'AccountController' does not exist in the current context` when referencing the `AccountController` in another project. I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you referenced the Dll of the AccountController on the WebApp project?

Comment: If this truly needs to be in a separate project, and that project is referenced by your web application project, then it sounds like you wouldn't be able to make that reference.  Worst case you can just use the literal string "ConfirmEmail".

Comment: Do you have the correct using statement and the correct assembly referenced?

Comment: I tried to use a literal string by changing `action: nameof(AccountController.ConfirmEmail` to `action: "ConfirmEmail"`, but then I get a different error: `The best overload for 'Action' does not have a parameter named 'action'`?